# Unity3d 4.5.0 missing textures after build

Tags: unity-game-engine

In the unity3d:
[image: in the unity3d]

After build for windows no textures:
[image: after build for windows]

What's happened?

UPDATE:

This is my project folder:

[image]

And this is TerrainGenerator object with TerrainGenerator script. Here i attached all textures. But still not working..

[image]

Comment: How do you assign textures to materials? Using scripts or using Unity editor?

Comment: @SergeyKrusch I generate terrain by the script and add textures too.

Comment: did you found a solution? I have the same problem now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

To fix this issue you need to create folder with name `Resources` in `<Your project directory>/Assets` folder. And move your textures there.

## Explanation

Usually, when building an application Unity will only take assets that are referenced somehow from your project (in scenes, in project settings, maybe somewhere else). But it doesn't analyze your sources (because it's not possible, in general). This is why your textures are not included in your build.

But there is special folder name: `Resources`. If you put folder with name `Resources` in `<Your project directory>/Assets` folder or in one of its sub-folders (you can have multiple `Resources` folders) then Unity will include every asset from it.

Comment: Oh, i am sorry, but i am update the project but it still not working. And i am update the question

Comment: Lol but if i am add to scene empty terrain, textures on my generating terrain showing)

Comment: What does output_log.txt say?