# Shader work in editor but is white in build

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I'm building a shader in unity graph and it's completely different in the editor than the build.

it's present and can be seen from the glasses reflection but not the color and the rest.

What am I doing wrong?

shader ([download shadergraph file](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/94f18ee1d817993323da3eec946c4eb120191010064632/6cbb15)
):

[image]

in editor:
[image]

resulted in build:

[image]

Comment: Do you use postprocessing, how is it set up?

Comment: The shader works on my device (Pixel), tested with the LWRP sample project, Unity 2019.2.8.

Comment: ah... so something sure is there.
ok, even if only standard stuff is active I try turning off every ppstack element. Let's see what happens.

(I've only disabled hdr for now)

Answer (score 0):

Do you load the textures you are using from code?
If so it could be that these textures are not included when you build your game (if they are not referenced anywhere else unity will [not include them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24183595/unity3d-4-5-0-missing-textures-after-build) in your build, since it doesn't check your source code).

Comment: I knew this problem. No, I am in Resouces and (usually) included in the preload asset. They are connected to a material that is applied to different models. They are not processed by script or other (simple material).

Comment: Glasses makes the reflection (even if it looks black on the published image, it does) so the shader, in theory, is there ... but it does nothing other than that.

I'm trying to improve it but it seems strange ...

Answer (score 0):

So I came accross this same issue and this was one of the only things that came up online when I searched. I seem to have fixed it so thought I should share.

It appears that there is something in the Blender export which is being detected in the editor but not carrying into the build. For some reason if I add the .blend object with no edits to it into the scene (note - you can have it disabled), this will then allow shaders to be loaded on all instances of the object. I have simply attached this to my prefab and called it "Texture Loader". Why this works I can't tell you.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't understand how but the problem was in the shader itself. in my opinion "It seems" that he ran into a strange bug. Who knows... Will remain a mystery!

thanks everybody

---

**[Solved with luck | Post Closed]**